# Terrible grade in undergraduate research project, how will this affect graduate admissions?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, research-undergraduate, grades, united-kingdom

I have graduated this year with a second class first division. In addition, I ranked sixth. However, the problem is that I scored a D+ in my undergrad research project. Now I am aiming to pursue a masters degree at UK. My supervisor did not show up regularly plus he was 2 hours far away from my place.

I am really worried if this is going to ruin my chances into getting accepted in a good university such as Glasgow, Sheffield, Bristol or Bath. Do you think I have a chance?

BTW: I am an international student majored in engineering.

Comment: Related (though sadly, unanswered) question: [How to mitigate bad grade in research on PhD application?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/27602/how-to-mitigate-bad-grade-in-research-on-phd-application)

Comment: Are you worried about admission to PhD or masters? A good masters project should (at least partially) compensate a not so good undergrad.

Comment: I'd be careful with the explanation "My supervisor did not show up regularly plus he was 2 hours far away from my place." Yes, it's unfair and understandable, but it also sounds like blaming others. As trite as it sounds, I'd focus on the lessons learned here. Also: Is there a way in which you can show that you acquired the necessary skills later? Personally, I got the worst passing grade in stats (undergraduate psychology -- due to a week of caffeine, which keeps you awake but turns your brain into concrete) and used my diploma thesis to show my competency in this area.

Answer (score 2):

> Do you think I have a chance?

**Yes.**

I was accepted to a masters program with some bad grades on my undergraduate transcript, some courses with less then 40% marks. In graduate school I got a distinction and now I'm a postdoc.

Doing poorly in a single course won't ostracize you from all graduate schools.

Answer (score 1):

Except at a handful of schools, taught MSc course in the UK are generally unfunded and not selective. Full fee paying international students are essentially the holy grail of students in the UK. With a 2.1 and 5-10k for fees you should have a large choice of good schools.